# Spring MVC IT Test failing because cant found the HTML page to return

Tags: java, spring-mvc, junit, integration-testing, thymeleaf

I am developing Integration Test (JUNIT) on a webapp based on Maven + Spring 5 + Thymeleaf and, when i run this test in Eclipse:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@Transactional
public class StackOverflowTest extends PruebaBaseTest {

    private static final String USER_CORRECT_USERNAME = "prueba@gmail.com";

    private static final String USER_CORRECT_PASSWORD = "prueba";

    @Autowired
    PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    User user;

    @Override
    @Before
    public void setup() {
        super.setup();

        //
        if (user == null) {
            user = new User();
            user.setFirstName("Test");
            user.setLastName("Test");
            user.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(USER_CORRECT_PASSWORD));
            user.setEmail(USER_CORRECT_USERNAME);
            user.setEnabled(true);
        }
    }

    @Test
    @WithMockUser(username = USER_CORRECT_USERNAME, authorities = { "ROLE_USER" })
    public void testPruebaView_HttpsGetWithGrantedPermission_ShouldReturnAltaView() throws Exception {


        final MockHttpServletRequestBuilder createMessage = get("prueba/alta").secure(true)
                .contentType(MediaType.TEXT_HTML);
        this.mockMvc.perform(createMessage).andDo(print());

    }

}
```

I get the following error:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: An error happened during template parsing (template: "ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/views/templates/prueba/alta.html]")
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:986)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:870) (....)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:978)
    ... 75 more Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/views/templates/prueba/alta.html]
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextResource.getInputStream(ServletContextResource.java:159)
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.templateresource.SpringResourceTemplateResource.reader(SpringResourceTemplateResource.java:103)
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parse(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:223)
    ... 87 more
```

However, if I run the app on Tomcat 8, it works perfectly, so I suppose that the problem happens when running the test, its context doesn't know how to find the path to the Thymeleaf templates (/WEB-INF/views/templates/).

How can I tell test environment that the path to templates is /WEB-INF/views/templates/?

If that is not the problem, please, correct me. If any more information is needed, feel free to ask for it, thanks.

Comment: Can you add the whole test class ?

Comment: @john , I edited the post and added the test class, hope it helps!

Comment: Does test pass when you run it from maven, i.e `mvn clean test`?

Comment: @SagarRohankar, No, it doesn't. I get the same error.